# Undo all the changes done by adview

Tags: java, android-studio, adview, banner-ads

I recently added an adview to my app. But dint knew anything about admob. I got an error bcz I didn't link it with admobId. So I deleted the adview from the layout. But the same error came again. I think the adview changed the scource code in many files like gradle, manifest etc. I don't know what changes shoud be undone. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

First of all delete the adview if u haven't.

Secondly delete the metadata in your manifest file

Thirdly open build.gradle(module:app)  and delete the implementation 'com.google..........ads:...

It helped me!